# How to do change an object to a number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this 'position1' df (and I am trying to sum my total portfolio's worth):

```
               total         Last_P
BNB       0.77063139    18.33230000
BTC          1.4e-07  5235.88000000
EOS           0.0073     5.82520000
ETH         1.31e-06   178.51000000
USDT     80.13510905            NaN
XRP              300     0.35374000
```

the above is an object and after using:

```
position1.info()
position1 = pd.to_numeric(position1, downcast='float')
#position1 = pd.to_numeric(position1, errors='coerce')#tried this
#position1.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x), axis=0)#tried this    
print(position1)
position1.info()
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

Please advice how to solve this

Comment: which line triggers that error?

Comment: Can you print `df.dtypes`

Comment: @Datanovice: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 6 entries, BNB to XRP
Data columns (total 2 columns):
total     6 non-null object
Last_P    5 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
total     object
Last_P    object
dtype: object

Comment: @Yuca 2nd and 3rd and 4th lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.to_numeric` only works on a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series as stated in the error that you mention. In order to apply it to a DataFrame, you need to use the apply method:

```
position1.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Note that, as most functions in pandas, this operation does not happen "in place" by default

Comment: This answer was flagged for low quality. Please explain what your proposed changes do.

Comment: What is the return value of the expression above?

Comment: this answer works, dtypes are float. So not sure what's wrong with your input

Comment: when doing: position1['Pos_Value'] = position1.total * position1.Last_P the results is:  TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: you need to reassign position1, the operation is not in place

Comment: dtypes: object(2)

Comment: Your variable `position1` has not changed, you need to work with the return value or reassign it e.g. `position1 = position1.apply(pd.to_numeric)`

Comment: @Giladbi Any luck?

Comment: @Chris thanks. my bad, i missed the df=... thanks again!